# How do you scale a set of number such that they sum to 0.5 after scaling

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

Suppose I have a set of numbers of various different values (>0.0). I want to scale these numbers so that they all sum to 0.5. The scaling is required so that the relative strength of the numbers with respect to the other numbers is retained as is, and the constraint that the sum of the numbers should be 0.5 after scaling is my requirement.

What is the actual mathematical way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this you can divide each number by twice their total sum. To see why this works, say you have a collection of $n$ numbers and denote them $p_i$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. Their sum is
\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i.
\end{equation}
Dividing each $p_i$ by $2S$ gives
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{p_i}{2S} = \frac{1}{2S} \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i = \frac{1}{2S}S = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
This preserves the relative magnitude of each number while scaling their sum, just as we wanted.

Comment: If I want the set to sum to 1000, do I just divide each value by 1/1000 of their total sum? Also, how does this question differ from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/278418/190742 which has a different answer?

Comment: The difference is that in their other question they want the total sum to be $1$, whereas here we want $1/2$. To make the sum $1,000$, you would multiply each number by $1000/S$, where $S$ is their current total sum.

Comment: Do you have any references for this solution?

Comment: This is just beautiful!